# Get initial position of an object in a variable and don't change the value of it

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to keep the position of an object in a variable and the value of it never be changed but Im not being able to do it.
My code looks like this:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform InitPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        InitPosition = transform;
        Debug.Log(InitPosition.position);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(InitPosition.position);
    }
}
```

I know that this code don't do something itself but I just want to see the result of the FixedUpdate Debug.Log be the same as the Start one.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Transform` is a class, which means that `InitPosition` stores a *reference* to the transform object. So both `InitPosition` and `transform` refer to the same object: if the object changes, you'll observe those changes whether you use `InitPosition.position` or `transform.position`.

`position` on the other hand is a `Vector3` which is a struct and therefore a value type, which has copy semantics. So store a copy of the position instead:

```cs
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 InitPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        InitPosition = transform.position;
        Debug.Log(InitPosition);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(InitPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh make so much sense, Im new using unity thank you for your help!